# I have to write a javascript function that takes in a string and returns true if "the string starts and ends with a vowel"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, ampersand.js

title basically. The question says create a function that takes in a string and returns true when the string starts and ends with a vowel. I must have read every possibly helpful/similar thread on here and still stuck. Please help

Tried too many things to even list. Its been literally hours I've been bashing my head against this problem.

Comment: Show a couple of your attempts, because this seems very easy to do, so I'm curious as what you're doing wrong that's resulting in errors. I understand that anything is easy once you know how to do it, but to test the first and last characters of a string to see if they're one character from a set of five (assuming the Latin alphabet) just doesn't seem difficult once you know how to create, and call a function.

Comment: This is a simple regular expression. The pattern `[aeiou]` matches a vowel. So write a regexp that matches this at the beginning and end.

Comment: we havent even been introduced to regexp yet, I have no idea what that is

Comment: Yes I'm sure it seems easy but I never wrote a line of code a day in my life until a week ago. toss me a bone here please. I don't have any of the code I already tried, I had to delete it each time I resubmitted to try and answer the question

Comment: Welccome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

```
function test( word ){

  word = word.toUpperCase();
  
  let last = word[ word.length - 1 ];
    
  let vowels = [ 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' ]

  if( vowels.includes( word[0]) && vowels.includes( last ) ){
    return true
  }else{
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

:-)

You know how to create and execute a function?

You understand what [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) with does?

You know the [&& (and) and || (or)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#logical_operators) operators?

Try something like this:

```
function startsEndsWithAVowel(aString) {
  return (aString.startsWith('a') || aString.startsWith('e') || aString.startsWith('i') || aString.startsWith('o') || aString.startsWith('u')) && (aString.endsWith('a') || aString.endsWith('e') || aString.endsWith('i') || aString.endsWith('o') || aString.endsWith('u'));
}
```

Add uppercase vowels too.

This solution uses only a few constructs. If You learn more JavaScript you come up much better solutions.

Comment: Thank you and yes the first few solutions I tried looked a lot like that. I was introduced to  those functions and operators; they were the first things I thought of and tried but maybe I had errors somewhere. I'll try and plug this answer in tonight after I finish and turn these in and get back to you about how it goes. I really want to learn this stuff.